# "Edit tags" link no longer focusing in tag editor area

Tags: bug, status-review, user-experience, inline-tag-editor

When you use the inline tag edit feature to quickly edit the tags of a question without editing the whole question, the field for the tags automatically received the keyboard focus. This meant you could immediately write a new tag which was missing. However, this feature is gone now, and you have to make an additional click into the input field to start writing.

Was this change intentional or is it a bug?

Comment: Weirdly on Meta the focus goes to the tag field but on main, it doesn't. Can't check other sites as I don't have 10k rep elsewhere.

Comment: I checked it on meta as well and the bug exists there as well (for me). But after I have cleared the browser cache, it is working for exactly one time. After that, it will not get the focus again. And when I clear the cache and test it on SO, it doesn't work there at least once. But how can the cache affect it in a way that it works once on meta and not once on SO (for me)?

Comment: Maybe this should be tagged as [feature-request] instead of, or in addition to, [bug]?

Comment: Definitely a regression, so I would say it's objectively a bug.

Comment: For the love of God will someone please fix this

Comment: @j08691: Agreed. Broken stuff (that used to work) ought [to be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367394) [in much less time than 6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369893/performance-delay-in-editor-when-moving-to-a-blank-line).

Comment: Ironically, the keyboard-only 'E' + 'TAB' is much faster (if profile setting *"Enable keyboard shortcuts"* is on).

Comment: Is anyone actually reviewing this? @CodyGray this is a one-liner fix, can't someone update the JavaScript and close this?

Comment: @j08691 Unfortunately, moderators don't have access to change the JavaScript code that the site uses. We are not employees, and we don't have developer access. You need someone who is employed by the company for that, which is the reason that I've added the [status-review] tag. The purpose of this tag is to mark the question as requiring attention from a staff member. Obviously, that hasn't happened yet. I have no other way of making it happen, aside from what I've already done, which is to confirm the bug and add a [status-review] tag.

Comment: Just came here to raise the issue, then found the question. I guess it's time to write another userscript...