# When viewing a question's edit history that includes tag edits, the opacity is broken when hovering over a tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, revision-history, tooltips

I noticed that when you view the edit history of a question with tag edits and hover over a tag that the opacity of the popup is broken.

[image]

Comment: Repros on this very question on MSO for me.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with this very post! Wow that's weird!

Comment: `z-index: 1002;`...

Comment: It works (on this very question at least) for me with Chrome 104 on Windows 10. What browser have you observed the problem with?

Comment: @DonalFellows Not sure what you mean by "it works". Are you saying that you're not able to reproduce the issue? Using Win 11 w/ Chrome Version 104.0.5112.81 (Official Build) (64-bit) here and still seeing it here and on SO

Comment: This is on me. Taking a look now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been addressed now. You may confirm the fix on this very post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/419802/revisions

This issue occurred while I was adding keyboard navigation support to our tag popovers as part of our [accessibility initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419586/announcing-design-accessibility-updates-on-so). It turns out we're using `clip-path` to animate the collapsible component here which creates a new css stacking context. Thus causing the painting order problem (different stacking contexts don't share the same z-index context).

I had to disable the collapse/expand animation for now to get rid of the issue. We will look into alternative animation strategies for a long term fix but this change should address the immediate issue.

Comment: Thanks Sal. Who's responsible for the long-time bug of the [edit tags field no longer receiving focus automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409081/edit-tags-link-no-longer-focusing-in-tag-editor-area)?